# Can't make my js to work in my bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/u4vfr280/

I have this between my "head" tags:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I've also added at the end of the body:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed off your javascript in your jsFiddle. Without modification, you're getting a

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

You need to add an extra to close of your $(document).ready() function.

```
})
```

at the end.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
        overlay = $('.overlay'),
       isClosed = false;

      trigger.click(function () {
        hamburger_cross();      
      });

      function hamburger_cross() {

        if (isClosed == true) {          
          overlay.hide();
          trigger.removeClass('is-open');
          trigger.addClass('is-closed');
          isClosed = false;
        } else {   
          overlay.show();
          trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
          trigger.addClass('is-open');
          isClosed = true;
        }
    }

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
          $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? You need to provide more information. Running what I have provided you in Fiddle works for me. Unless there's something wrong with you JS/jQuery external references.

Comment: @DavidKramer Those errors are thrown: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function

Gonna check the font bootstrap cdn.

Comment: I've tried updating the font-awesome cdn but still throw this error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Also this error:

Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function(anonymous function) @ main.js:1

Comment: First, it can't find your main.js (your path is wrong) and it also doesn't know what your $(document).ready is. You're including it at the bottom of your page, but are using this code presumably in the header. You need to include it before you want to use jquery.

Comment: @Pablo, I see you posted an answer to this? Did you solve it? What did you change?

Comment: @DavidKramer I've just aded a $ before my (document).ready(function () {

Comment: @Pablo, that was in your jsFiddle to begin with...anyway, glad you figured it out.

Comment: I think someone updated it, it wasn't in my js file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just fixed the problem by adding this to my js:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
        overlay = $('.overlay'),
       isClosed = false;

      trigger.click(function () {
        hamburger_cross();      
      });

      function hamburger_cross() {

        if (isClosed == true) {          
          overlay.hide();
          trigger.removeClass('is-open');
          trigger.addClass('is-closed');
          isClosed = false;
        } else {   
          overlay.show();
          trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
          trigger.addClass('is-open');
          isClosed = true;
        }
    }

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
          $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    })
});
```